# I can't download the Codename One plugin in NetBeans because of NBM

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-plugins

I'm trying to install the Codename One plugin in NetBeans 17 but i get a message saying The validation of downloaded plugins cannot be completed, cause: NBM. Don't really know what does mean, what should i try?

That is the only thing i have tried. Don't know what else to do

Answer (score 0):

We no longer support the plugins as newer IDE versions broke compatibility. They are here only around to support legacy ant projects.

You need to use Maven projects they don't work with a plugin.

A maven skeleton for any IDE can be generated here: https://start.codenameone.com/